# About the Erdős-Borwein Constant

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, real-numbers

The **Erdős-Borwein Constant** can be found in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-BorweinConstant.html

My question is : Is there is a document or website containing the value of $E$ with a bigger number of digits after the comat.

Comment: From the formula $\;\displaystyle E=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^n-1}\;$ you may quickly find thousand of digits (1 mn for $10^4$ digits on my old computer). How many do you want?

Comment: May not be a true reference, but wolfram alpha gives 1.6066951524152917637833015231909245804805796715057564...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example the free [pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) to get :

```
> \p 10000
> sumpos(n=1,1/(2^n-1))
= 1.606695152415291763783301523190924580480579671505756435778079553691418420743486690565711801670155575897045429063154413100090547320500886191363162159598905709967807317603346256346194412169271471143875877005193100895641758091648494880166136371577175297784032810889796524656778476222123398647471544551530180717454033712249541188738074175027726616919950855065362156926682541986718548677094187723291230010547544293549570799498285544959377213281337880503447193724882117880144512910386486141279029576440184734626025794655667942118668692103208760055385996965942262320378135463745976866396518368649735187266977868979382770434476475719866503498018470997114032072724203387654474508365604514524850766198860764752017232805057468943598023310578599066455210311859824270501015480673546705382305016905807360213660654713624379559365621819964999106229274370686240151828644217475411749422319321824497642387322226326994856586610772781076752472383656368967065485151435936066265493806548037147193022942530536720456804128379148631409387888919313857992546119862449905318227203945253243808056408467219399728990292448723191448913588548279032302444067857170221106725811646927870264020616865214966881543541547246984045043978572491201872919712280655798250658840688587783846552938388939978391770388403498018370078873502484866292395666737230331987550159944300821526119229674953106381107434161368742270295845231832686322164419241998928109769527090863632194534460555347377018110578651165648018843810077022113932961556868267524015673383210842569973869303014174485382138918810576974915461003871535171323978070168195416309933195148454080011265153974506329765682248307074174891297319963601617560423348713515069042791430029468305782061388716519796511306633462759100418622441026151937260556225845654244316588657342716413958325878120189180413819902239267430935500334635789224209247630219390172692420015088554099662104327198907947432942350251272721975007245208067110294422732316204172932419644827584439297865397745421033245748320079670259018515855767245404071413191080420598805567750676633880039060946617138056390907606125349892099896650210154319338165440864853733731989340414774229503354876902673644686301838857117099968793050891382305694322796467980385005766305282185519391207692219942852699696029529445803229855333339819436744882135762795514006482574407709040993028617616856403268804214352097248828967374979884561086962140922498670312556772683283120935389258690940681426622262973061286533139114494937222392543104169191550510302537916456032635113042577856362812188320722195085046476874373998347654520054451590263243429484347874809704994681145118082829620124654803338366203628026406048074580723185278536042428954098538684269021849547144597692370373138611596106033761292734526710179928492205844261499735358199261145197230059011689962660966057875602988961851644641849142420053711685495022797258076553700983328156784436140013365422404376975599536178876721555937068738215172681954519852765113426929414291736777281043369070105634275902723186210166588712766671779893175406813548418043811218026582884318329172415600173584604954502394578976536144929583097658255751693437602244629677189075850407087643382753724738369778508376044116207292668754882668060397454965209385196015972633112605203414934460963298166939678815960769875841019222265893368199046006752351816303837712000260583299698663612205723676431556608709612209160489846894981972482874291153480220763108274073179748673465084530551742038896072277909360957062805046845989988883178405587541562867060366006697382860991849031796488081249733812980553408620653402461654976543828707497120911450973991756427752682290818065748484204582334302112559776674046976797437510309918421932775203556984360025130573154818716822205411186612658923093777189814638451913417078314584553668809069796096104007333559458690585806402069855190738106343197878942545240097446500169601831520939166347049674724862793676396248788700186853129566163405319162506108741860757801378104464998573375982612476430906834380623200325251619819116084307649388729217995245411319383072585971361543577664526358120615470125633139453236075531096728791835975547864939110154623554948776215879744614738905985763084615299292269973953384180752472911781099049491516087701717478196971717927467655722512763658655495522321756386626772945626110014475769895312726667325905676293668372496939205744404594852099154456130366789115672105927252922003799527533295013006195510858233991770991544931696139441009063558510827091455498874752291111524177170557009042456335348596156421239405144194963890306465846977801041856302361212033783410806190208326105165738841081339841022321209321976488739885278425731780005787759401200231277615199983365048091806348786522565014134976806022573115830465192926727141596662407167836711145428829526148491974974750310800120911481541127820495395584859651129026801126291816972154803405501843178339897323184626749368697936714832172659102823036125738545684083968911209088298941821506889435070876810432929149723133408461718563640834603171213950276019173848362879775520096059546816438650960617109289843299168773322604885157084374718067005197612230990001357305154325026541701711077344636570483827813549763358008725323387816758232753869881299915071170766464513949175784619148114883152517686363141096492280329319777373089085363465272054811712989904135440988854302656269816646637747562402468409189885310436070566863515173186044284661780308137896916423770641702839541295979380859916181997742063687644875878925156470729670562196386175694820852185234583147382588495485666969429855165287772170773824199327755605920388980537592346287259944393658779024453478950727797184644995544349458191483291724720065004069972221229255096306287603977542105136797544993526404735215080308446270729682051074803262923678427076733126421909479069269120578849895828447724119151696782837765168568656603785257060533168409007372609997315675388563315309657500797784128471923524471269636178127784141312187437912032071917928384177023337869970880467815409671657920528441570055178504616480351389536620028554807295868118677318025141115024878097238740647044229499071013329494238000286261561698239761247980203098266666385454110448396723974239615029311376678291986574143328749901578186184018351871395817529502264843860073616024369174058848223104484810621320489736465518796141695235452890855549501770332597811207329429663038473677672354005767853621973752910327064686667321273196727847244280337198721046369638099100045958284333240492028473627734073088101247917841257273564031527263248626798592090769586529517198885665608068948949466249502879318799120475249853281785339286516396502352110961125425162149128209365936118003093257055165621093707517888172101029943523903728457385171682761813774766363861610527771639227030336809931939083724174642839176444207015472288017071143467230565472756232781630073463458214136432634306128454225954508103604063321810377326054907032419203122252519558468686602485215850025648205686023046180518625708708046287913153834231523617305578101881771564016480162885462160266270014185218946691702677673997675885833045053952692047610555572749309347871150749178287781450205585092576960336149257442183668045407567534062109352354893060747351447558093157825118714218561547337095441969250944764000149800098661678390714958377466401227282855285858366744480088383386389967406435596478132518650875375890730261403718540764728840917475765116094877593683710828155003918231757348672045613288467723033001404049019648909395673809467414006770366535754412005426809743420511106113581573724411536170950269284557562171716833758829610070097173744104733884669892773582144908879474384892459323105221978823195165252844883256637594446505200672036330671498019044075766278953781550942767944849462102144938236965398788671190062187414777115661983916598574548478255191483739413024469717624185803541983497293697476280409006782242774711180036075042138232876880839109853659959207263427497424408588104593420811382403561063458278542125568953123034998235877597614314516676853963136706553285980724282382773575723578685464303963233188932115274679581507560028953189450652454132465196354910553952347379932707286608097144097002787832683688291355256247536149138563930840250267310544209572726532962550951595802985425074993194257502370286767755380523627344990408847007410308002485533763799873412959369492406149702705533887256610198570372177895623048699715064910895912142929554784363770122392365259200419723952942073362801621508540264928143204119910225155273868209143193420793798932057230772612238879389927498605730028406494233904625634112629674156636099903572759076757591011816484676858624749448361395597007747487510634001616490590985955003414357253628228714215390181675734751090445124331963892471051722351312800154460660998461478120277008813457515857408779877487729332157784742173846434521827798979445174293115737530785501277327166020347541631027408052571440116959552577128873278706220956416289769022755325273123235338700771578334261971905014136042833053914270399301513461934836262077558392888550975243762612539329302756897261815789308736389699937390408198682175691988910047378004636417828395882044430439287376721095548828005614304233909037963084475087536738816550237233159892165580974539429708985664861445288655852981473791988317713268664740089220046904046746595202017727962159098164405211895693236879063538826114766794429781889713648053208106121704846921017140251959176828794619090757101355545574681303152982471081436975694835192084590757993514425148648830951768024302709745470914986295125170477226270781681628808960764212634404976481138630135080589798841764122627665890470043808197894918412496335422848581552332810506510039305794870507580101569342650749484956279287030560978323265767931700357870818033102066529195554821155783129195425481965981463299652122389820016695566779867390832839809266909728967349892677008488803620406322527979709093740427745878149249117682713422760108983436432015084872948069762856610228862641979095329473415234874337775497951013930736808099006146439815897882698832278631447254828262817811
```

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20-%20QPolyGamma%281%2C1%2F2%29%2Fln%282%29) evaluates $1-\dfrac{\psi_{1/2}(1)}{\ln 2} =$ 1 - QPolyGamma(1,1/2)/ln(2) as

$1.606695152415291763783301523190924580480579671505756435778079...$

For more digits, go to the link and click on "More digits".